# Find div from this in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html in a loop (same code but different `data-post-id`)

```
<div class="vote">
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="1" class="vote-arrow vote-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>
    <div class="total-vote">0</div>
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="-1" class="vote-arrow vote-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></div>
</div>
```

If someone clicks on on the second div I want to change the color to red.

- All divs are black in the beginning.
- If someone clicks on on the div with class vote-up I want to change the color to red.
- If someone clicks on the div with class vote-up again nothing will happend.
- If someone clicks on the div with class vote-down, the div with class vote-up should be black and the div with class vote-down should be green.

The problem is that I have I have three states. I tried to use to add the class enabled and this (the success function) is as far as I have come now.

```
$(".vote-arrow").click(function () {
    var postId = $(this).data("post-id");
    var voteRank = $(this).data("vote-rank");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Posts/Vote/",
        data: { postId: postId, voteRank: voteRank },
        context: this,
        success: function () {
            switch (voteRank) {
                case 1:
                    if ($(this).closest(".vote-arrow").hasClass("enabled")) {
                        $(this).css({ 'color': '#000' });
                        $(this).addClass('enabled');
                    } else {
                        $(this).css({ 'color': '#d9534f' });
                        $(this).addClass('enabled');
                    }
                    break;
                case -1:
                    $(this).addClass('enabled');
                    $(this).css({ 'color': '#5cb85c' });
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the flow. click up (up red, down black), click down (both black), click down again (up black, down green), click up (both black), click up again (up red and down black). Black is the default value, you have not voted.

Comment: First, there are only 3 divs. Second what should happen on 1st and 3rd click?

Comment: Rows in the code not div. Can update my code. But buttons is the one with generated ID.

Comment: I guess I still dont understand your requirement.

Comment: Can you clarify if 'div' with class "vote-arrow vote-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" is second div or first?

Comment: Edit my post. Easer to understand? Only two divs to care about with class vote-up and vote-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like K Scandrett said, something like Remove and Addclass, but in your case you should expand the selector.

```js
$('.vote-arrow').click(function()
{
  if($(this).parent().children('.vote-arrow').hasClass('enabled'))
  {
     $(this).parent().children('.vote-arrow').removeClass('enabled');
  }
  else
  {
     $(this).addClass('enabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.vote-down.enabled
{
 color: green;
}
.vote-up.enabled
{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote">
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="1" class="vote-arrow vote-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>
    <div class="total-vote">0</div>
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="-1" class="vote-arrow vote-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote">
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="1" class="vote-arrow vote-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>
    <div class="total-vote">0</div>
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="-1" class="vote-arrow vote-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost what I'am looking for. 1. You click up-arrow and it's geting the color red (correct). 2. (up-arrow is red) and you click the down arrow. In your example the down arrow gets green and the up arrow gets black. Both should be black (the default value, the initial state before you start voting). 3. If you click the down arrow again it becomes green. The flow. click up (up red, down black), click down (both black), click down (up black, down, green), click up (both black).

Comment: I changed it, so it uses the idea of Loading.., only with the "enabled" class which you created.

Comment: As written above this does break the requirement of clicking the down arrow a second time when it shouldn't turn black again. Just saying :)

Comment: That was not specified i think.And it is marked as the solution, so I think it is correct.
The flow specified: "The flow. click up (up red, down black), click down (both black), click down (up black, down, green), click up (both black)." is not broken. NEVERMIND: Read the requirements again and my solution is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

First part of the code 'voteUp' is to simulate your ajax return value.

```
$('div.vote-arrow').click(function(){

  var voteUp = $(this).hasClass('vote-up') === true ? 1 : 0;

  if (voteUp) {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('green');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('red');
  }
});
```

And set up the classes for 'green' and 'red'

EDIT:

```
$('div.vote-arrow').click(function(){

  var voteUp = $(this).hasClass('vote-up') === true ? 1 : 0;

  if (voteUp) {
    if ($(this).parent().children().hasClass('red')) {
      $(this).parent().children().removeClass('red');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('green');      
    }
  } else {
    if ($(this).parent().children().hasClass('green')) {
      $(this).parent().children().removeClass('green');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('red');      
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the jsbin http://jsbin.com/qipoguqipu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This is almost what I'am looking for. 1. You click up-arrow and it's geting the color red (correct). 2. (up-arrow is red) and you click the down arrow. In your example the down arrow gets green and the up arrow gets black. Both should be black (the default value, the initial state before you start voting, same as you have not voted). 3. If you click the down arrow again it becomes green. The flow. click up (up red, down black), click down (both black), click down (up black, down, green), click up (both black).

Comment: Mershi's answer has a better selector `.children('.vote-arrow')` than I the generic one I used.